# Linux kernel 3.3 apps on Android

Tags: android, linux-kernel, processing

There was a recent article that Linux kernel 3.3 has integrated Android as one of the features.

It has also created the possibility of launching Linux applications on Android systems provided the correct drivers are used.

I am currently learning Android app development using Processing language.

I am comfortable with processing language in Windows/Linux operating systems. If I develop a processing application in Linux kernel 3.3 that uses bluetooth communications, is it possible to port it to Android?

If yes, How should I go about doing that?

To summarize my question, Can I port my Linux based processing language apps to android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linux binaries have always been able to run on an Android system assuming the proper libraries are available (such as in a chroot).  See, for example, [Debian & Android Together on G1](http://www.saurik.com/id/10), the first released Android device.

What is happening more recently is that Android kernel modifications are merged or being prepared for merging into the mainline Linux kernel.  This doesn't directly benefit desktop Linux users (who weren't using those additional features anyways) nor Android users (who will continue using Android's kernel), but will hopefully reduce divergence and make ongoing development and maintenance easier.

It also gives rise to the potential of running the Android userspace stack on a mainline Linux kernel, whether on a Android device or not.

Comment: I wouldn't say that this won't directly benefit Linux or Android users. If all goes well, it will eventually be possible to run a full Android stack on top of the mainline Linux kernel. Linux users will benefit by being able to run Android apps natively, and Android developers will benefit by having a larger user base.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly no.  You see, Android is based on the Linux Kernel, on top of that are all of the drivers for the specific device and on top of all of that is the Android OS.  You need to write code that makes Android OS calls through the sandbox that your app is in.